# How to split string in two parts

Tags: java

I'm retrieving Strings from the database and storing in into a String variable which is inside the for loop. Few Strings i'm retrieving are in the form of:

`https://www.ppltalent.com/test/en/soln-computers-ltd`

and few are in the form of

`https://www.ppltalent.com/test/ja/aman-computers-ltd`

I want split string into two substrings i.e 
`https://www.ppltalent.com/test/en/soln-computers-ltd` as `https://www.ppltalent.com/test/en` and `/soln-computers-ltd`.

It can easily be separated if i would have only `/en`.

```
String[] parts = stringPart.split("/en");
System.out.println("Divided String  : "+ parts[1]);
```

But in many of the strings it has `/jr` , `/ch` etc.

So how can I split them in two sub-strings?

Comment: `String[] parts = string.split("-")`

Comment: @Jarrod I reopened this, since the main problem I see here is understanding what pattern to split upon. That is not explained (for this context) in that dupulicate.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, I'm not sure this is in fact a duplicate of that question.

Comment: same way you split them now either with `.split()` or with `.substring(indexof("condition"))`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Yes, but `condition` is perhaps not obvious to the OP.

Comment: D'oh, now I'm the one doing bad closing. Can someone vote to reopen? I've already used my one reopen vote. I forgot the OP needs to split the string rather than just obtain the last segment. @aioobe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You could perhaps use the fact that `/en` and `/ja` are both preceeded by `/test/`. So, something like `indexOf("/test/")` and then `substring`.
- In your examples, it seems like you're interested in the very last part, which could be retrieved by `lastIndexOf('/')` for instance.
- Or, using look-arounds you could do

  ```
  String s1 = "https://www.ppltalent.com/test/en/soln-computers-ltd";

  String[] parts = s1.split("(?<=/test/../)");
  System.out.println(parts[0]);  // https://www.ppltalent.com/test/er/
  System.out.println(parts[1]);  // soln-computers-ltd
  ```

Comment: Doesn't split remove the splitting string? So wouldn't you just get "https://www.ppltalent.com" ?

Comment: In the last suggestion? You're right. However, that's a positive look behind. So it splits on the zero-width string following `/test/../`.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I i'm looking to have two sub-strings i.e (a)
1. https://www.ppltalent.com/test/en and 2. /soln-computers-ltd
(b) 1.https://www.ppltalent.com/test/ja and 2. /aman-computers-ltd

Comment: @Littlebird, this can be achieved with any of the three solutions I suggest. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any of the options.

Answer (score -1):

Split on the last /

```
String fullUrl = "https:////www.ppltalent.com//test//en//soln-computers-ltd";
String baseUrl = fullUrl.substring(0, fullUrl.lastIndexOf("//"));
String manufacturer = fullUrl.subString(fullUrl.lastIndexOf("//"));
```

Comment: You've mixed up `/` and \ I believe :-)

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Why do you have `//`? Looks like you're trying to escape a `/`.

Comment: Whoops, I escaped them